# Reason I have to fix git remote for new branches

Tags: git, config, git-checkout

I have already found at least 3 different ways to fix this git problem, so that is not what this question is.  First, the problem:

I have a repo cloned from our gitlab server to my laptop.  I made changes in my master branch, ran "git checkout -b newBranchName", and with git gui, committed and pushed.  But "git pull" complains "There is no tracking information for the current branch. ..."  It's true.  The problem is that .git/config indeed has no entry for my newBranchName.  But I think that it should.

While git is highly generalized to work with N remotes and all, it makes some assumptions, too.  The config file shows several variables with default (assumed) values, and I like them all.  But I want it to also assume that if I have only one remote in my config file, for master, then that's the same remote for any new branches I make with "checkout -b".  If it's ever an incorrect assumption, I can fix it.  I just don't want to HAVE to fix new branches every time.

So really, I have two questions.  One, why does git make no assumption about remote for my new branches?  Two, am I doing something wrong when I create new branches?

Comment: How did you push?  Did you use `-u`?

Comment: I pushed from "git gui" -- I don't know what it used under the hood.

Comment: You can see the executed commands with `git gui --trace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do anything wrong in particular as far as I see.

You can set the default remote for all branches with

```
$ git config remote.pushdefault <remote name>
```

It can be overridden for particular branches with the `branch.<branch name>.pushremote` setting.

This only spares you of providing the name of the remote when pushing. You still have to tell git to set up a tracking branch if that is what you want. You can do that with `--set-upstream` or `-u` for short. This essentially sets up the `branch.<branch name>.merge` option to the correct value but is more convenient. This is only needed for pushes and only for the initial one. When fetching a new branch for the first time, git sets up tracking information automatically (except you change `branch.autosetupmerge`).

Comment: That does eliminate having to make a fix for every new branch, and the command is only needed per repo.  Close enough -- that's the ticket!